# Get all values of Enum with specific integer value c#

Tags: c#

How to get all values of enum with integer value in this example

```
enum colour { red = 1, green = 1, blue = 1, yellow = 2, cyan = 2, purple = 2 }
```

I mean, by inputting 1, I want output red, green, blue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, firstly I would *strongly* recommend that you don't do this.

Having multiple names for the same value is a really bad idea, IMO. However, you *can* do it with reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 1,
    Blue = 1,
    Yellow = 2,
    Cyan = 2,
    Purple = 2
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var name in GetColorNames(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetColorNames(int value)
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Color))
                   .Where(name => (int) Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), name) == value);
    }
}
```

Personally I would have separate values in the enum instead, and then have a `Lookup<int, Color>` or something like that. Aside from anything else, it would be very confusing to have something like:

```
Color color = Color.Blue;
```

... and then see `Red` in the debugger or other diagnostics...